# Node, Express + Jade load script once

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using Node, Express and Jade to render 3 pages of a website. I simply serve the pages as:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home');
});

router.get('/mid', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('mid');
});

router.get('/final', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('final');
});
```

I plan to use jQuery on '/mid' and on '/final' pages, so I simply added the following at the end of mid.jade and final.jade:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='jquery-min.js')
```

My question: if a user opens '/mid' and later '/final/ then the user downloads jQuery twice. Is it possible to setup something similar to this without having jQuery load twice? I can think of multiple client-side solutions, but I am curious if I could do it somewhat similar to the current code?

Edit:
jQuery wasn't a good example, let's take a scenario where on '/mid' and '/final' I have the same script with:

```
var a = [];
```

And on '/mid' I push some items into the array then on '/final' I'd like to use those values, so reloading the script isn't good as it'll empty it.

Comment: User's won't download jQuery twice. After they download it the first time, their browser should cache it.  In fact, if you serve jQuery from a cdn, it's more likely that they'll already have that version of jQuery, and won't need to download it at all when they visit your site.

Comment: Good point, I have to edit my question to reflect my issue here, I tried to simplify it as much as possible and oversimplified it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common script tag src file will simply be cached by the browser so it won't be reloaded on the second page.

A custom script tag with content embedded into your page cannot be cached by the browser independently because it's embedded in the page and the browser only caches whole files.

If you want to populate the same array in two different templates, then you will literally just have to hook up the same code to both templates so that the same code populates them in both templates.  You can't "save" the results from one template and then use that in another template.

You could put your javascript array into a sub-template (or partial or include or whatever jade calls them) so that the same sub-template was used in both pages.  Then, you'd only have to configure the rendering of that array once in the sub-template and the same code would be used for both pages.

Remember, no Javascript state survives from one page to the next - a completely new environment is created for each new page so whatever you want the Javascript environment to be in a given page, you have to initialize it to that yourself - it will not "keep" any state from the previous page.  You can consciously save state from one page to the next either server-side in a database or client-side in a cookie or LocalStorage, but to make use of that you have to specifically write code that saves the state to the storage location and then code that reads it from there when applicable.

But, it sounds like what you want is to just initialize the array the same in two pages which should work fine with a sub-template or just referring to the same template code in both pages.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking something same along the lines, but I wanted some confirmation. As I wrote I can think of possible solutions (similar what you wrote) but then it requires "bigger" changes. Thanks for the answer!